# scrapy handle hebrew (non-english) language

Tags: scrapy

I am using scrapy to scrap a hebrew website. However even after encoding scrapped data into UTF-8, I am not able to get the hewbrew character. 
Getting weird string(× ×¨×¡×™ ×‘×¢×ž) in CSV. However If I check print same item, I am able to see the correct string on terminal. 
Following is the website I am using. 
http://www.moch.gov.il/rasham_hakablanim/Pages/pinkas_hakablanim.aspx

```
class Spider(BaseSpider):
    name = "moch"
    allowed_domains = ["www.moch.gov.il"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.moch.gov.il/rasham_hakablanim/Pages/pinkas_hakablanim.aspx"]

    def parse(self, response):

        data = {'ctl00$ctl13$g_dbcc924d_5066_4fee_bc5c_6671d3e2c06d$ctl00$cboAnaf': unicode(140),
                'SearchFreeText:': u'חפש',
                'ctl00$ctl13$g_dbcc924d_5066_4fee_bc5c_6671d3e2c06d$ctl00$txtShemKablan': u'',
                'ctl00$ctl13$g_dbcc924d_5066_4fee_bc5c_6671d3e2c06d$ctl00$txtMisparYeshut': u'',
                'ctl00$ctl13$g_dbcc924d_5066_4fee_bc5c_6671d3e2c06d$ctl00$txtShemYeshuv': u'הקלד יישוב',
                'ctl00$ctl13$g_dbcc924d_5066_4fee_bc5c_6671d3e2c06d$ctl00$txtMisparKablan': u'',
                'ctl00$ctl13$g_dbcc924d_5066_4fee_bc5c_6671d3e2c06d$ctl00$btnSearch': u'חפש',
                'ctl00$ScriptManager1': u'ctl00$ctl13$g_dbcc924d_5066_4fee_bc5c_6671d3e2c06d$ctl00$UpdatePanel1|ctl00$ctl13$g_dbcc924d_5066_4fee_bc5c_6671d3e2c06d$ctl00$btnSearch'}

        yield FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                        formdata=data,
                                        callback = self.fetch_details,
                                        dont_click = True)

    def fetch_details(self, response):
        # print response.body
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item = MochItem()
        names = hxs.select("//table[@id='ctl00_ctl13_g_dbcc924d_5066_4fee_bc5c_6671d3e2c06d_ctl00_gridRashamDetails']//tr/td[2]/font/text()").extract()
        phones = hxs.select("//table[@id='ctl00_ctl13_g_dbcc924d_5066_4fee_bc5c_6671d3e2c06d_ctl00_gridRashamDetails']//tr/td[6]/font/text()").extract()

        index = 0

        for name in names:
            item['name'] = name.encode('utf-8')
            item['phone'] = phones[index].encode('utf-8')
            index += 1
            print item # This is printed correctly on termial. 

            yield item # If I create a CSV output file. Then I am not able to see proper Hebrew String
```

The weird thing is, If i open the same csv in notepad++. I am able to see the correct output. So as a workaroud. What i did is, I opened the csv in notepad++ and change the encoding to UTF-8. And saved it. Now when i again open the csv in excel it shows me the correct hebrew string.

Is there anyway to specify the CSV encoding, from within scrapy ?

Comment: `I am not able to get the hewbrew character.` Where?

Comment: getting error,  exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd7 in position 33: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: can you post the full stacktrace to see what component or which line of code breaks? Be aware that the program reading your CSV file should expect UTF-8 encoding ; sometimes you need to specify that setting when opening the file.